# Add dynamic dependency to shared object in C++

Tags: linker, g++

I want to create shared object B that dynamically links to shared object A. I'm using the following command to compile shared object B:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -L/path/to/directory -lA -o libB.so B.cpp
```

It is my understanding that `-lA` is what tells the linker that `libB.so` should dynamically link to `/path/to/directory/libA.so`. However, when I do `ldd` on the final product, the dependency is not listed (and loading `libB.so` fails because of these missing dependencies).

```
ldd libB.so

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd4233e000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f35072fe000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f35070e7000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3506de1000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3506a1c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3507807000)
```

Am I wrong about what `-l` is supposed to do? I assume that the above is a minimal set of dynamic dependencies from C++.

Are there any gotchas to look for? For instance, does the linker simply ignore `-l` requests when it can't find the file or something (and I have to debug my paths more than I already have)?

Do I have to put something in my C++ code to indicate dependency (like "extern" functions or something)?

**Update:**

I have determined that the set of dynamic dependencies that `ld` reports *does* depend on my C++ code and *does not appear to* depend on any `-L` or `-l` flags I supply. The linker is automatically guessing which shared objects my `libB.so` should depend on, and it's not assuming enough.

For instance, I know that I'll need B to load A because I call some code that eventually calls code in `libA.so`. How do I provide this information to the linker?

**Clarifications:**

What I'm calling "shared object A" is a complex thing that may load some code dynamically. I want to include enough dependencies so that it will not fail with "missing symbols" when it tries to load this code dynamically. That's why I want to force dependencies in B, because the linker might not statically find them in the dependency tree.

Also, I'm using g++ 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 14.04). This is relevant because g++ started implicitly applying `-Wl,--as-needed` as of version 4.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the dependency is not listed in the `ldd`'s output because no symbols which are used in `B.cpp` are found in `libA.so`. This may happen because of C++ symbol names mangling: if `libA.so` has been compiled by the C compiler, it may store the symbol for function `void foo()` under pretty name `foo`, whereas C++ compiler will mangle it into something like `_Z3foov`. You can check it with the following commands:

```
$ # Replace "SomeSharedObject" with the actual name of symbol exported by libA.so.
$ strings libA.so | grep SomeSharedObject
$ strings libB.so | grep SomeSharedObject
```

To avoid this, one could put the declaration of the symbol `foo` into an `extern "C" {}` clause. Then compiler will not mangle this name, and linker will probably find this name in `libA.so`.

The `-l` option works as you expect in a laboratory environment:

```
$ cat bar.cpp 
extern void foo();

void bar()
{
    foo();
}
$ cat baz.cpp 
extern void bar();

void baz()
{
    bar();
}
$ # Link against libssl.so (OpenSSL).
$ # Obviously libssl.so is unnecessary in libbar.so.
$ g++ -fPIC -shared bar.cpp -o libbar.so -lssl 
$ ldd libbar.so 
    statically linked
$ # Link against libbar.so in the current directory
$ g++ -fPIC -shared baz.cpp -o libbaz.so -L`pwd` -lbar
$ ldd libbaz.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7cfe2000)
    libbar.so => not found
```

Here `libbar.so` depends on the function `foo`. But it hasn't been found in any library, including `libssl.so`. So `ldd` reports the shared object `libbar.so` as "statically linked". All symbols which were not found when `libbar.so` was produced, will be searched for when creating the final executable which depends on `libbar.so`.

In turn, `libbaz.so` depends on `libbar.so`, because the function `void bar()` was found in the above shared object which we have specified via `-l` option. If we omit the `-L` option, linker would report error like `-lbar: not found`. If we omit both `-L` and `-l`, `libbaz.so` would not depend on any shared object just as `libbar.so`.

Comment: I'm compiling C++ against C++. In particular, the library I'm linking against (A) requires `-std=c++11`, though my library (B) is generic enough for any version of the standard. But there's no pure C code anywhere.

Comment: Actually, the "works as you'd expect" example illustrates the behavior that surprises me. You explicitly tell `libbar.so` that it should depend on `libssl.so` and it ignores your suggestion. (I created a simple example like that, too, just to be sure.) Considering that `-l` ignores redundant libraries and throws compilation errors on insufficient libraries, how come I'm in a situation where I can compile a library B, yet it fails to load due to missing symbols that I know are in A? ("A" is a huge project with `.so` files depending on other `.so` files. I want to link against _enough_ of them.)

Comment: @JimPivarski "fails to load due to missing symbols that I know are in A" -- my guess is that there is some spelling mistake in symbol names in A or B, or A is not actually exporting the symbols which B requests. Have you tried running `strings` on `libA.so`?

Answer (score -2):

You are compiling to a weird object name. Linking will happen when you create an executable. *then* you have to mention your various objects and libraries.

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: I deliberately used conventional names in my example. Which name do you think is weird? (I'm asking just in case I'm missing the point because of something like this.)